# Regex to filter matching lines only with a word

Tags: regular-expression

I have the following input:-

```
 res: 1234 web1 S-SSID_Active Paid 
 res: 7890 web2 S-SSID_Inactive Pending
 res: 1111 web3 S-SSID_Suspended Stopped
 res: 4444 web3 S-SSID_New Paid
 res: 6666 web3 S-SSID_Unknown unknown
 res: 7777 web3 S-SSID_Interest invalid
```

---

```
^.*?\b(S-SSID_Active|S-SSID_New|S-SSID_Interest)\b.*$
```

Need to filter lines only with above words.

Comment: Using bash tools?

Comment: You haven't told us what regex tool / dialect (BRE?ERE?PCRE?emacs?) you are using